# PHP & Mysql : filter by date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter list of all upcoming meetings 
So far i am using this query

```
$sql = "SELECT *  from demo_meeting WHERE created_by_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = '$get_user_name') AND venue_id IS NULL AND meeting_datetime  >= curdate()  ORDER BY meeting_datetime ";
                    mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                        // Print out the contents of each row into a table
                        //date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
                        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');   // Change it as per user requirement
                        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
                        if ($date > $row['meeting_datetime']){
                        ?>
                        <tr><td>
                        <div class= "main" style ="margin-top: 5px; padding: 15px 14px;background:#fff">
                              <div class = "bold"  > Name :<?php echo $row['name']; ?><br> </div>
                              <div class = "bold"  > Date :<?php echo $row['meeting_datetime']; ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "clear"></div>
                        </td></tr>
                <?php
                        }}
```

Why this above statement is not printing the upcoming meetings ?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions? And can you show us the result of `print_r($result)`?

Comment: Resource id #8   this is what i am getting print_r($result)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you do `meeting_datetime  >= curdate()` and the opposite afterwards `if ($date > $row['meeting_datetime'])` ?

So, just replace > by < or <=

Comment: Or do this all by mysql, no need to do this in PHP

Comment: Yep, he is already doing this in MySQL, he's using a double check, don't know why.

Comment: actually here my logic is if current time is 15:00:00 of any day then i want to show the all meetings after 15:00:00 so far i am doing double validation